# Define a route for url ending with integer in python

Tags: python, flask, routes

Here is a portion of my python code:

```
@app.route("/<int:param>/")
def go_to(param):
    return param
```

The above function routes a url such as `www.example.com/12` to this function.

How can I declare a parameter rule to redirect urls ending with integers, such as `www.example.com/and/boy/12`, to this function?

I'm using the Flask framework.

Comment: use '/and/boy/<int:param>' in the route() decorator. No other change needed.

Comment: @NitzanShaked the OP wants a rule for every url that ends with an integer. `/and/girl/<number>`, `/and/boy/<number>`, `/and/anything/<number>`, `anything/<number>` and `/<number>` would all follow the same rule

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need `Werkzeug routing`.

*Complete code:*

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

app = Flask(__name__)

class RegexConverter(BaseConverter):
        def __init__(self, url_map, *items):
                super(RegexConverter, self).__init__(url_map)
                self.regex = items[0]

app.url_map.converters['regex'] = RegexConverter

# To get all URLs ending with "/number"
@app.route("/<regex('.*\/([0-9]+)'):param>/")
def go_to_one(param):
    return param.split("/")[-1]

# To get all URLs ending with a number
@app.route("/<regex('.*([0-9]+)'):param>/")
def go_to_one(param):
    return param.split("/")[-1]

# To get all URLs without a number
@app.route("/<regex('[^0-9]+'):param>/")
def go_to_two(param):
    return param

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: the second part without a number is not working for url such as www.example.com/asd/ase/avi78

Comment: The regex I have given just checks for URLs without any numbers, that's why. Just use `'.+'` to match all URLs, or tell me what you are looking for.

Comment: What I wanted was to check for url ending with alphanumeric such as avi78 as in www.example.com/yuk/avi78

Comment: I doubt if slash is missing dere since it is the ending of url

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22874/discussion-between-jade-and-atoztoa)

Comment: i think this will do @app.route("/<regex('.*\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'):param>/"), but as u said in dat way it will only check for numbers and dat too in the whole url

Comment: This will give you the last field in the URL after the last `/`. Is it that you need?

Comment: ys i wanted to check only the last portion but get the whole sub url,i hope it will work fine.By sub url i mean /asd/ert/567 part in www.example.com/asd/ert/567

Comment: Then use this: `'(.*[0-9]+)'`.

Answer (score 21):

You just need to add "and/boy" to your parameter:

```
@app.route("/and/boy/<int:param>/")
def go_to(param):
    return param
```

Comment: i meant a general rule to handle url ending with an integer like www.example.com/and/boy/12

Comment: It doesn't cover all the cases. The user is clearly asking for a generalization.

Answer (score 1):

```py
@app.route('/profile/<username>')
def profile(username):
    return f"you are in {username} page"
```

you can pass the parameter with any data type if you need a specific data type for example integer like this

```py
@app.route('/profile/<int:id')
def profile(id):
    return f"your profile id is {id}"
```